# create-react-app only creates package.json file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create react app using command create-react-app test.
This command only creates a project directory with package.json file.File containing...

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
```

Node version 11.11.0 &
NPM version  6.7.0 
with cmd Same issue
[image: with widnows CMD]

with bash CLI it is also creating error
[image: with bash CLI it is also creating error]

Comment: Can you post the output from terminal after running “$ npx create-react-app test2”?

Comment: Would also be helpful to see your environment: “$ npx create-react-app —info”

Comment: i have edited the question with screen shoot please see the given images

Comment: Try reinstalling: show the output for “$ npm i -g create-react-app”

Comment: Can you verify that C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe exists on your system. On which partition is Windows installed? This looks like an issue with cmd path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give this a try:

- npm install -g create-react-app
- create-react-app my-app

Comment: it updates things from npm install -g create-react-app
then when i run create-react-app my-app. It installs things that i need not only package.json. Thank you

Comment: Didn't change a thing for me !

Answer (score 1):

If you are windows user the reason could be you have windows(32 bit) with Node(64 bit) or vice versa. The solution is install node(32 bit) for windows(32 bit) and same for 64 bit too.

Answer (score 1):

In mac OS,
I just added 'sudo' like this

```
sudo npx create-react-app my-app
```

And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same with me!
`npx create-react-app my-app` was just creating package.json file for me. But I waited for some time and found that my terminal was still active and was installing some more scripts which is actually responsible for creating some directories and files inside'em which we're looking for.

If this doesn't helps, you can run the following in your terminal:

`npm install -g create-react-app`

This will install the required dependencies to load the directories which should be pre-loaded at the time of creation of a react-app!

Comment: An how do you deactivate the terminal